# Update field in SharePoint list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsom

I'm trying to update a SharePoint list using Javascript and I found this code.

It's working sometimes but mostly giving me this error

> "Request failed. Unexpected response from server.null"

Here is the code i'm using.

```
function Myfunc()
{
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateListItem, "sp.js");
}

function updateListItem() 
{
GetMail();
}

mail = [];
PlainMail =[];

function GetMail() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://MyURL/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Notifications')/items?
  $select=ServicesId,Author/Id,Author/Name&$expand=Author/Id&$top=50000",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data){

       window.field =
```

document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl49_g_fd8fcb6f_98bf_4dbf_a73e_1ea566ba0d64_ff61_ctl00_Lookup").value;

```
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
           fullname = item.Author.Name;
          window.mailadd = fullname.replace("i:0#.f|membership|","");
            var id = item.Author.Id;
            var mailid = id + ';#' + window.mailadd;




            Array.prototype.contains = function(elem) {
                for (var i in this) {
                if (this[i] == elem) return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
                var arr = item.ServicesId.results;
                if (arr.contains(window.field)){
                PlainMail.push(window.mailadd)
                mail.push(mailid)
                }              


                });

       ;

       mail = mail.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
       return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
         })

     FindMailGroup()
    },

    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
 }    



function FindMailGroup() {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://MyURL_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('MailGroups')/items?
$select=Service/Title,ServiceId,ID&$expand=Service/Title",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data){

        /* For each item in the list build the HTML code*/
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){


           if (window.field== item.ServiceId) {
            window.rowId = item.ID;
            window.notificationtext = item.Service.Title


       }


                });

       ;
     updateList();
    },

    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   });
   }    

   var siteUrl = 'https://MyURL/';


   function updateList (){
   var newmail = (mail.join(";#"));
   var NewPlainMail = (PlainMail.join(";"));
   console.log(window.rowId);
   console.log(window.PlainMail);
   console.log(NewPlainMail);

   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
   clientContext.load(clientContext.get_web())
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MailGroups');

   this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(window.rowId);
   oListItem.set_item('ServicePlainText','');
   oListItem.set_item('PlainMail','');
   oListItem.set_item('ServicePlainText',window.notificationtext);
   oListItem.set_item('PlainMail',NewPlainMail);

   oListItem.update();


  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
  this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }

  function onQuerySucceeded() {

   console.log('Item updated!');

  }

  function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

  console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + 
  args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

Comment: Do you use this code in SharePoint Add-in ?

Comment: No, it's running from a Content Editor.

Comment: Sometimes it gives me the error but the list has been updated anyway

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using this script within SharePoint CEWP, so you should use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method to delay the function call until the `(SP.js)` is loaded.

So try to do following:

```
function Myfunc()
{
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateListItem, "sp.js");
}

function updateListItem() 
{
    // your code
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Myfunc");
```

For more details check [Sharepoint 2013 Request failed unexpected response data from server. null](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/084db342-8c22-4c85-bf49-54e7562c65ba/sharepoint-2013-request-failed-unexpected-response-data-from-server-null?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I'm using CEWP but the script is only loaded when a save button is clicked in a form.

Comment: Should it be before all of my code or just the update list part? I have tried both but I still get the error.

Comment: Please share your full code to can help you faster also to try it in my side

Comment: Should be there now

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Could you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the item since its client script. I believe since you aren't loading the item you are receiving that null error. You need to load items using this method [ClientContext.load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903.aspx).

Comment: Could you point me in the direction on how this is done?

Comment: I think if you just add `clientContext.load(clientContext.get_web());` after you create the client context it should load everything from the site for you to use. If you want to only load specific lists or items you just change the argument for `load()`, which takes client objects. Look at that link I posted in the answer for the documentation.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Then try the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method that @M.Qassas recommended. I think the error is definitely happening because something from the site isn't loaded when you try and use it. Good luck.